# Facing Issue in AzureOpenAI connection with SQL Database

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain, azure-openai

I have done below code for connecting the AzureOpenAI with SQL using langchain, but it is failing,

```
from langchain.agents import create_sql_agent
from langchain.agents.agent_toolkits import SQLDatabaseToolkit
from langchain.sql_database import SQLDatabase
from langchain.llms.openai import AzureOpenAI
from langchain.agents.agent_types import AgentType

db = SQLDatabase.from_uri("mysql://user:pwd@localhost/db_name")
toolkit = SQLDatabaseToolkit(db=db, llm=AzureOpenAI(deployment_name="trailadvisor",model_name="text-davinci-003",temperature=0))

agent_executor = create_sql_agent(
    llm=AzureOpenAI(deployment_name="trailadvisor",model_name="text-davinci-003",temperature=0),
    toolkit=toolkit,
    verbose=True,
    agent_type=AgentType.ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION,
)

agent_executor.run("Describe the XYZ table")
```

Error: **openai.error.InvalidRequestError: Invalid URL (POST /v1/openai/deployments/trailadvisor/completions)**

Any suggestions or link from which I can get reference.